# Logic or lookup table: Best practices

Tags: function, matrix, logic, lookup

Suppose you have a function/method that uses two metric to return a value — essentially a 2D matrix of possible values.  Is it better to use logic (nested if/switch statements) to choose the right value, or just build that matrix (as an Array/Hash/Dictionary/whatever), and then the return value becomes simply a matter of performing a lookup?

My gut feeling says that for an *M*⨉*N* matrix, relatively small values for both *M* and *N* (like ≤3) would be OK to use logic, but for larger values it would be more efficient to just build the matrix.

What are general best practices for this?  What about for an *N*-dimensional matrix?

Answer (score 1):

The decision depends on multiple factors, including:

- Which option makes the code more readable and hence easier to maintain
- Which option performs faster, especially if the lookup happens squillions of times
- How often do the values in the matrix change? If the answer is "often" then it is prob better to externalise the values out of the code and put them in an matrix stored in a way that can be edited simply.
- Not only how big is the matrix but how sparse is it?

Answer (score 0):

What I say is that about nine conditions is the limit for an if  .. else ladder or a switch. So if you have a 2D cell you can reasonably hard-code the up, down, diagonals, and so on. If you go to three dimensions you have 27 cases and it's too much, but OK if you're restricted to the six cub faces.
Once you've got a a lot of conditions, start coding via look-up tables.

But there's no real answer. For example Windows message loops need to deal with a lot of different messages, and you can't sensibly encode the handling code in look-up tables.

Comment: What are you talking about, "ups", "downs", "diagonals", and "cube faces"?